# PHP redirect to custom url with some data

Tags: php

in my simple webservice i want to post some data to user custom url with redirect to that. for example after use simple transaction in my server i must be pass some data to user `redirect_url`, i think this code can be post but i can not redirect to and show posted data

```
public function redirect_to_customer($result = [], $redirect_url = "")
{
    $ch = curl_init($redirect_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $result);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_exec($ch);
}
```

and this code dont work currectly :

```
function redirect_to_customer($result = [], $redirect_url = "")
{
    ?>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function closethisasap() {
                document.forms["redirectpost"].submit();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="closethisasap();">
    <form name="redirectpost" method="post" action="<? echo $redirect_url; ?>">
        <?php
        if (!is_null($result)) {
            foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . $k . '" value="' . $v . '"> ';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
}
```

i get html code on web URL like with :

```
http://sample.com/%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Chtml%3E%20%20%20%20%3Chead%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20charset=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first fix your second function redirect_to_customer function and do not place html code out of php but assign it to some php variable then echo it like this

```
function redirect_to_customer($result = [], $redirect_url = "")
{
    $html = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function closethisasap() {
            document.forms["redirectpost"].submit();
        }
    </script>
</head>........';
echo $html;
}
```

othervice that html will be outputed where it included